# Can't handle WM_KEYDOWN message

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to handle WM_KEYDOWN message using following wndproc and winmain but when I press a key(i.e. arrow keys which ascii value 24, 25, 26, 27) it doesn't handled.

`WndProc`

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    /*TO CHECK uMsg message*/
    char buff[256];
    _itoa_s(uMsg, buff, 10);
    SetWindowText(hEdit, buff);
    /**********************/
    switch (uMsg)
        case WM_CREATE:
            hEdit = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "Edit", "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE |ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE | ES_WANTRETURN | WS_VSCROLL, 735, 5, 150, 100, hWnd, NULL, hInst, NULL);
            HButton1 = CreateWindowEx(NULL, "BUTTON", "START", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_CENTER, 2, 2, 80, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_BUTTON1, hInst, NULL);
            HButton2 = CreateWindowEx(NULL, "BUTTON", "B", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_CENTER, 82, 2, 80, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_BUTTON2, hInst, NULL);
            HButton3 = CreateWindowEx(NULL, "BUTTON", "STOP", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_CENTER, 162, 2, 80, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_BUTTON3, hInst, NULL);
            Hmainbmp = CreateWindowEx(NULL, "STATIC", "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_BITMAP | WS_THICKFRAME, 1, 23, 600, 500, hWnd, NULL, hInst, NULL);
            break;
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
            PRESSED_KEY = wParam;
            break;
        case WM_COMMAND:
                    break;
            case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return(DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam));
    return(0L);
}
```

`WinMain`

```
int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow){
    MSG      msg;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HMENU MainMenu, FileMenu;
    MainMenu = CreateMenu();
    FileMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
    AppendMenu(FileMenu, MF_STRING, IDC_OPEN, "Open");
    AppendMenu(MainMenu, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)FileMenu, "FILE");

    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW);
    wc.lpszMenuName = lpszAppName;
    wc.lpszClassName = lpszAppName;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.hIconSm = (HICON)LoadImage(hInstance, lpszAppName, IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) return(FALSE);

    hInst = hInstance;
    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, lpszAppName, lpszTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 900, 600, NULL, MainMenu, hInstance, NULL);


    if (!hWnd) return(FALSE);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

Why below case doesn't work? And how can I handle WM_KEYDOWN?

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:
    PRESSED_KEY = wParam;
    break;
```

**UPDATE**

When I minimize and maximize window again, `WM_KEYDOWN` processed but if I click any button, it isn't working.

Comment: Probably because the WM_KEYDOWN messages are going to the edit control you created.

Comment: If you want to intercept the keyboard messages going to the edit control you have to use a technique called [window subclassing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview).

Comment: Also note that Arrow keys are handled special as they are reserved by the OS for navigation purposes by default, so they don't generate `WM_KEY...` messages by default. You have to explicitly ask for that by handling the [`WM_GETDLGCODE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/wm-getdlgcode) message to return the `DLGC_WANTARROWS` flag.

Comment: @john Actually, I want to change the value of a global variable(PRESSED_KEY) when key pressed. hEdit is just to see the value.

Comment: Keyboard messages only go the the windows that has the focus. The user can change which windows has the focus by clicking on a window. So if you really want to track all keyboard use then windows messages aren't the best way. Maybe you should be looking at [SetWindowsHookExA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) although I have no experience with this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3487834/17034

Answer (score 1):

According to the [`WM_KEYDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown) document:

> Posted to the window with the keyboard focus when a nonsystem key is pressed. A nonsystem key is a key that is pressed when the ALT key is not pressed.

However, there are other buttons and edit boxes in your window. So when you press other buttons or click on the edit box, the focus will be on that window.which causes the `WndProc` function to be unable to process the `WM_KEYDOWN` message.

You can use the [`SetFocus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setfocus) function to set the keyboard focus window.Then you can get the `WM_KEYDOWN` message through the main window, and display the value through the Edit control.

Like the following code:

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:
    PRESSED_KEY = wParam;
    _itoa_s(wParam, buff, 10);
    SetWindowTextA(hEdit, buff);
    break;
```

Of course, if you don't want to focus on a specific window to get keyboard information, I recommend you use the [`SetWindowsHookEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) function to get the global keyboard message, without focusing on a specific window.

**Edit:**

If you want to handle all `WM_KEYDOWN` messages, you can use the `SetWindowsHookEx` function.

You only need to modify a few parts of your code:

1.Add a function to handle the keyboard:

```
LRESULT __stdcall KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    char buff[256] = "";
    PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT key = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;
    //a key was pressed
    if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN && nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        _itoa_s(key->vkCode, buff, 10);
        SetWindowTextA(hEdit, buff);
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

2.Set the hook process to the keyboard in the main function:

```
HHOOK _k_hook;
int WINAPI WinMain(_In_  HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_  LPSTR szCmdLine, _In_  int nCmdShow)
{
    MSG      msg;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HMENU MainMenu, FileMenu;
    _k_hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardProc, NULL, 0);
    ...
}
```

3.Finally, don't forget to delete the hook process after the program ends:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    HWND HButton1, HButton2, HButton3, Hmainbmp;
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        ...
    case WM_DESTROY:
        if (_k_hook)
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(_k_hook);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
        ...
    }
}
```

In this way, you don't need to process the message of `WM_KEYDOWN` in `WndProc`. The message of pressing the key is processed in the `KeyboardProc` function, and the value of the key is displayed in the Edit control.

Comment: I want `WndProc` to  process all `WM_KEYDOWN` messages. Can you share examples you suggested?

Comment: @No_0n3 I have updated my answer and you can refer to it.